# Execute task in background in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tap

Example

```
private void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int progress = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        progress++;
        Logger.Info(progress);
    }
}
```

What is the recommended approach (TAP or TPL or BackgroundWorker or Dispatcher or others) if I want `Start()` to

1. not block the UI thread
2. provide progress reporting
3. be cancelable
4. support multithreading

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58836/Using-Background-Process-in-WPF

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute task in the wpf background while able to provide report and allow cancellation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348125/how-to-execute-task-in-the-wpf-background-while-able-to-provide-report-and-allow)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With .NET 4.5 (or .NET 4.0 + [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async)), the best way is to use `Task`-based API and `async/await`. It allows to use the convenient (pseudo-)sequential code workflow and have structured exception handling.

Example:

```
private async void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int progress = 0;
            for (; ; )
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                progress++;
                Logger.Info(progress);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

More reading:

[How to execute task in the WPF background while able to provide report and allow cancellation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357567)

**[Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx)**.

[Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

[Async/Await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx).

Comment: Can I use multithread and multicore if I use Task based API? By the way, BackgroundWorker able to do calcellation and progress reporting. What are the difference between BackgroundWorker and Task based api?

Comment: @publicENEMY, `Task`-based API makes `BackgroundWorker` obsolete, read this: [Task.Run vs BackgroundWorker](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/Task.Run%20vs%20BackgroundWorker). `Task.Run` uses a `ThreadPool` thread to run your task, so yes, it certainly supports multithreading and multicore. There's some learning curve, but very well worth it.

Comment: @publicENEMY do not worry about multiple cores. The Operating system assigns threads to cores (known as _processor affinity_) and tries to use all the cores if it can! Any method for asynchronous programming uses `Thread`s if you drill down deep enough.

Comment: Since I can only mark 1 answers, Im gonna mark Task Based Api just because its newer. AFAIK, BackgroundWorker can also be considered answer. Thanks.

Comment: @publicENEMY, `BackgroundWorker` can still be used successfully, and low-level thread API like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or `new Thread()` can get the job done, too. Although, it wouldn't be so pleasant to code it as with `Task`/`async`/`await`, IMO.

Comment: +1 for the added resources one more url that I found helpful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: @Noseratio The answer is not complete, point 3 (Cancellation) is missing here in your code example! It would be nice if you would add it, without users having to leave SO proposed by your link.

Comment: @Legends, I have a complete example in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357567/1768303).

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is a bad practice in `async`! `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);` must be replaced with **`await Task.Delay(1);`**

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is used in this specific case to simulate a quantum of synchronous CPU-bound work, which is being offloaded to a pool thread (rather than for creating delays). That's what the question was about.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is by using a `BackgroundWorker`.

The reason I point this one out is it is specially designed to process work in the background while leaving the UI thread available and responsive. It also has built in `Progress` notifications and supports `Cancellation`.

I suggest looking at a few examples of a the **[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**.

Now when you start looking into the background worker there is one point `Cancellation` that you will have to dig deeper into. Setting the cancel property of a background worker doesnt cancel the background worker, this just raises a flag for your running method to interogate at regular intervals and gracefully stop processing.

Here is one of my posts from awhile ago talking about cancelling a background worker https://stackoverflow.com/a/20941072/1397504

Finally. Asyncronous does not mean multi-core or even multi-thread. ([WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony))

Comment: You were right about BackgroundWorker support cancellation and progress reporting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute an operation on a separate thread in WPF using the BackgroundWorker Class.

check this example [How to use WPF Background Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483565/how-to-use-wpf-background-worker)

And read about the class on MSDN here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: I totally forgot about BackgroundWorker. I was under the impression that BackgroundWorker are for Winform and WPF equivalent is Dispatcher class. By the way, AFAIK BackgroundWorker doesnt support multithread. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: "The most reliable way to create a multithreaded application is to use the BackgroundWorker component. This class manages a separate thread dedicated to processing the method that you specify. " From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck8bc5c6.aspx

Comment: @publicENEMY background worker is a helper class for running async operations and reporting progress You can use it in winforms and wpf because the `SynchronizationContext` mechanism is consistent for both. Every winforms object wraps an instance of `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` (allowing access to the UI thread) but WPF exposes the _actual message pump_ as a `Dispatcher`/ This contains a `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`.

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior Thanks for the link. Makes it easy to decide.