# How to execute task in the wpf background while able to provide report and allow cancellation?

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I want to execute a long running task after clicking a wpf button. Here what I did.

```
private void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // simulate task
    }
}
```

Problem is, this will make wpf gui unresponsive. I also would like to allow cancellation and report progress every 1 second. I expand the code as below.

```
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); // get progress every second
    private int progress = 0; // for progress reporting
    private bool isCancelled = false; // cancellation

    private void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeTimer(); // initiallize interval timer 
        Start(10); // execute task
    }

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Info("Current loop progress " + progress); // report progress
    }

    private void Cancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // cancel button
    {
        isCancelled = true;
    }

    private int Start(int limit)
    {
        isCancelled = true;
        progress = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // simulate task
            progress = i; // for progress report
            if (isCancelled) // cancellation
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return limit;
    }
```

My target platform is .NET 4.5. What is the recommended way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll likely want to use Tasks and async/await. They were built with exactly this in mind.

Comment: @publicENEMY, as you tagged your question with `task-parallel-library`, you should specific if you can target .NET 4.5 (or .NET 4.0 + [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute task in background in WPF application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326601/execute-task-in-background-in-wpf-application)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Since that other question didnt emphasize cancellation and progress reporting, none of the answer provide solution to cancellation and progress reporting. This question is basically a rewrite that other questions.

Comment: @publicENEMY since that other question is *your* question, you could have edited your question to emphasize what you needed instead of asking essentially the same question again, which will only result in diluting the answers.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Okay. What should i do now? Should I delete the other question?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I thought I answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21327014/1768303). If you need more sample code on how to do this using Task Parallel Library, with `CancellationTokenSource` and `IProgress<T>`, here it is:

```
Action _cancelWork;

private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.StartButton.IsEnabled = false;
    this.StopButton.IsEnabled = true;
    try
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        this._cancelWork = () => 
        {
            this.StopButton.IsEnabled = false;
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
         };

        var limit = 10;

        var progressReport = new Progress<int>((i) => 
            this.TextBox.Text = (100 * i / (limit-1)).ToString() + "%");

        var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        await Task.Run(() =>
            DoWork(limit, token, progressReport), 
            token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    this.StartButton.IsEnabled = true;
    this.StopButton.IsEnabled = false;
    this._cancelWork = null;
}

private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this._cancelWork?.Invoke();
}

private int DoWork(
    int limit, 
    CancellationToken token,
    IProgress<int> progressReport)
{
    var progress = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        progressReport.Report(progress++);
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // simulate a work item
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    return limit;
}
```

Comment: `IProgress<T>` interface is available from .Net 4.5 and not before that.

Comment: @RohitVats, `IProgress<T>` is available for .NET 4.0 with [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async), which is a production quality library. It can also be easily replaced with a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` one-liner.

Comment: Right. Needs NuGet library to get it work. But how it can be replaced by `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`? That is used to put delegates on dispatcher asynchronously. How that is related to report Progress?

Comment: @RohitVats, `IProgress<T>.Report` is **asynchronous**. When created, `Progress<T>` captures the synchronization context of the UI thread. Then, when `Report` is called from the worker thread, it uses `SynchronizationContext.Post` internally, not `SynchronizationContext.Send`. In case with `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`, the `Post` is a wrapper around `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. The implementation of `Progress<T>` is trivial, if you check it with Reflector or a similar tool.

Comment: Fair enough. Now I get it what you are trying to say. It got me thinking that how `Progress<T>` can be replaced by `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. This line `Post is a wrapper around Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` makes perfect sense. :)

Comment: +1 for hiding cancellation into `cancelWork` lambda.

Comment: What is the recommended way to handle ThrowIfCancellationRequested?

Comment: @publicENEMY, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21392669/1768303), it shows how to differentiate a cancellation exception from others.

Comment: @Noseratio So basically, catch OperationCanceledException and do nothing/something and carry on. By the way, +1 on Action for cancelling work. I now dont have to reset cancellation token values everytime I started Task.

Comment: @publicENEMY, basically yes, but it totally depends on your ViewModel. You need to make sure that the model (and hence the UI) remains in the integral state.

Comment: In the statement, await Task.Run(() => DoWork(limit, token, progressReport), token);, why token is passed twice? why progressReport isnt passed twiced? Thanks.

Comment: @publicENEMY: 1) it's passed to `DoWork` so it can do `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. 2) It's also passed to `Task.Run` itself. The goal for this is that if `token` is already in cancelled state, the task won't even start, `Task.Run` will throw `OperationCanceledException` instantly.

Answer (score 3):

`BackgroundWorker` is what you are looking for instead of DispatcherTimer.

It provides support of Cancellation (via ***WorkerSupportsCancellation***) and reporting progress back on UI thread (via ***WorkerReportsProgress***).

Refer to excellent detailed article here - [How to Use BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` can get the job done, but it's superseded with TPL: [Task.Run vs BackgroundWorker](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/Task.Run%20vs%20BackgroundWorker).

Comment: That's completely dependent on how complex is code. Underneath both are using ThreadPool. Also `IProgress<T>` interface is available from .Net 4.5 and not before that.

Comment: I've addressed the same point about `IProgress<T>` in the [comments to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21357567/1768303).

Comment: Is this Silverlight dependent?

Comment: @FizxMike - BackgroundWorker, IProgress<T> and TPL are independent of Silverlight and WPF.