# C# Threading/Async: Running a task in the background while UI is interactable

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

After looking around on both Async/Await and Threading, I'm still unsure of the right way to apply it to my situation. No matter the variation that I try my UI still hangs because I don't seem to be calling my desired function asynchronously, additionally, I may in fact need threading for my solution.

**What I'm trying to do:** I have a WPF application on which there is a button that I would like to start an operation that still allows interaction with the program, through UI or otherwise. Once a condition is met that is determined outside of this function, the function should end. To me this sounds fairly standard but I have a feeling I'm misunderstanding something and I've implemented it incorrectly.

**What I have right now:**

```
private async void start_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await StaticClass.MyFunction();
}

private void stop_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StaticClass.stopFlag = true;
}

public static Task<int> myFunction()
{
    //Stuff Happens

    while(StaticClass.stopFlag == false)
        //Do Stuff

    //Stuff Happens

    return Task.FromResult(1) //I know this is bad, part of the reason I'm asking
}
```

I was hoping for some guidance on if I'm approaching this the right way and any insight on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: **A complete example**: [How to execute task in the wpf background while able to provide report and allow cancellation?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21357567/1768303)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You've definitely implemented it incorrectly. You're returning a `Task<int>`, but only *once all the work has already been done*.

It seems to me that you should probably just have a *synchronous* method:

```
private static void MyFunction()
{
    // Loop in here
}
```

Then start a task for it like this:

```
Task task = Task.Run((Action) MyFunction);
```

You can then await that task if you want - although in the example you've given, there's no point in doing so, as you're not doing anything after the `await` anyway.

I'd also agree with Reed that using a `CancellationToken` would be cleaner than a static flag somewhere else.

Comment: Good one! Just do give Karoly some other hint, which helps me in separating this: Because so many sources say something like "... await starts a new thread ..." people think that await does all the magic stuff. It helped me a lot to think of await as a helper function for not messing with waiting for the result. Threading still rulez!

Comment: @sprinter252: Do they? I haven't seen any articles claiming that await starts a new thread. I've seen people *assume* it does, but no real *sources* claiming that it does.

Comment: Okay, things are making a bit more sense now, thanks Jon! Follow up question for ya, whats the difference between your second code snippet and @ScottChamberlain's second code snippet? Does yours just handle a return value of Task? If I don't actually need to return anything would your recommendation change?

Comment: @KarolyS: Nothing, really - it's just that Scott's inlined the loop whereas I've kept it in a separate method.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. I'll try to find some so that you get something to laugh about.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet Of course, Task.Run method is only on .Net 4.5 :)

Comment: @AliBagheriShakib: Yes, but the OP is already using `async` which is at least suggesting that they're using .NET 4.5. If they're using the async targeting pack, I'm not sure whether that *also* includes Task.Run - I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @JonSkeet how to pass parameters to function?

Comment: @TejpalBh: This should be a new question, including what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 10):

You did misunderstand.

```
public static Task<int> myFunction()
{
    //Stuff Happens

    while(StaticClass.stopFlag == false)
        //Do Stuff

    //Stuff Happens

    return Task.FromResult(1) //I know this is bad, part of the reason I'm asking
}
```

All of that code still happens in the intial `await StaticClass.MyFunction();` call, it never returns control to the caller. What you need to do is put the loop portion in to a separate thread.

```
public static async Task myFunction()
{
    //Stuff Happens on the original UI thread

    await Task.Run(() => //This code runs on a new thread, control is returned to the caller on the UI thread.
    {
        while(StaticClass.stopFlag == false)
            //Do Stuff
    });

    //Stuff Happens on the original UI thread after the loop exits.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to use a `bool` for this, you should consider using the [managed cancellation framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) built into the framework.

Basically, you'd build a `CancellationTokenSource`, and pass a `CancellationToken` to your method which could be used to handle cancellation.

Finally, your current method will never get off the UI thread.  You'd need to use `Task.Run` or similar to move the method to the ThreadPool if you don't want to block the UI.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could look into using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class to do the job, your UI will stay interactive.