# Why Selenium Webdriver freezes the Windows Form Appliaction?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Anyone out there can help me with this problem. I have searched it even on google but find nothing. I have made a Windows Form Application for scraping some data. Problem is this when i click on the button the script starts in a headless mode and i am using Chrome Web-driver. It then freezes the application in a sense it did not let us use the other buttons on the application while running the script.

> There's any solution to it or any other framework or thing which i can
>   do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that your application is single-threaded. Means that all the code it executes, is run on a single thread. So you don't have a way to do some work while your user is changing the UI state and viceversa.

A good solution is to run the "selenium script" (or the routine that fires it) on a thread that is not the one your application is using for the UI.

You can achieve this in some ways:

- Using the [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2) Class
- Using the [Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.7.2) Class
- Using a [BackGroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) Class that come within' Windows Forms.

Always remember that your default execution thread (in Windows Forms) is the one that keeps the UI and your application alive.

Answer (score 0):

Put the actual work in a background task and not into the click handler of the button.

Comment: background task?

Comment: Running a task in the background why UI is interactable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419229/c-sharp-threading-async-running-a-task-in-the-background-while-ui-is-interactab