# How to make a void method inside a for loop to run in async way

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a for loop and inside this for loop, it has a `void` method which would generally take time.
I want to run this `void` method in an `async` way and want to call `printFinalMessage()` after `doStuff(ele)` is completed for all the `ele` in `list`.

```
for (int ele in list)
{
    doStuff(ele);
}

printFinalMessage()
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you mean asynchronous, or do you mean multithreaded? If `doStuff` is meant to be `async`, why doesn't it return an awaitable such as a `Task`?

Comment: Is doStuff I/O or CPU bound?

Comment: Where is this code located? Is it in the `Click` event handler of a button for example?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest just using a [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) loop. This will process elements *concurrently*, but not *asynchronously*. Meaning the loop will go faster, but `printFinalMessage` will only be printed when all items have actually completed processing:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, ele => {
    doStuff(ele);
}
printFinalMessage();
```

This assumes that `doStuff` is an regular synchronous method. If it return a task you should probably use `Task.WhenAll` to create and task representing the completion of all of the tasks.

You might want to *also* run the entire loop in a background task, so the UI does not freeze while the loop is running. See [how to run a task in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21419280/12342238).

Comment: I like to specify the `ParallelOptions` when using the `Parallel.ForEach`, to prevent the default unlimited parallelism: `ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I believe that the default behavior will not start more work than there are cores as long as the work is compute limited, so the usefulness of MaxDegreeOfParallelism should depend on circumstances. And there is also things like partitions, local init and other potentially useful features I think are to advanced for an answer like this.,

Comment: My opinion is that the default value `-1` is not a good default, and I have asked Microsoft to revision the advice offered currently in the docs, but my arguments [weren't convincing enough](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72981 "ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism documentation, is the given advice correct?"). I have posted in that thread a couple of experiments, with results that some people might consider unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword for your question is **await all tasks** this is [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-7.0) from microsoft, add your task to a list and await all of them. Notice that the signature of `DoStuff()` is  `Task`

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3};

var taskList = new List<Task>();

foreach(var ele in list)
{
    taskList.Add(DoStuff(ele));
    //or you can write like
    //var task = DoStuff(ele); 
    //taskList.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

public Task DoStuff(int ele){ }
```

Comment: `Task` would actually be enough. `async` is technically not part of the signature.

Comment: Mind that for CPU- Bound operations this may be _not_ the best of ideas.

Comment: OK, remove the async

Answer (score 0):

What @JonasH said, but if you make `doStuff` async¹ then you could use `Parallel.ForEachAsync`²:

```
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new () { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = N };

var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    source: list,
    parallelOptions,
    async (i, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i), cancellationToken); 
        // or await doStuffAsync(i, cancellationToken);
    });

printFinalMessage(); // Called all work (3 pieces of work in this example) is done.
```

---

¹ - a real async; not a pretend async with - for example - `Task.FromResult`

² - available from .NET 6