# Background thread loop and two-way-communication

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I already used `BackgroundWorker` and `Task` to do something in the background and after it posting it back to the UI. I even used `BackgroundWorker` and `ReportProgress` with an endless-loop (beside cancellation) to continuously post things to the UI thread.

But this time I need a more controllable scenario:
The background thread continuously polls other systems. With `Invoke` it can send updates the the UI. But how can the UI send message to the background thread? Like changed settings.

In fact I am asking for the best .NET practice to have a worker thread with these specifics:

- Runs in background, does not block UI
- Can send updates to UI (`Invoke`, `Dispatch`)
- Runs in endless loop but can be paused, resumed and stopped in a proper way
- UI thread can send updated settings to the background thread

In my scenario I still use WinForms but I guess it should not matter? I will convert the application to WPF later.

Which best practice do you suggest?

Comment: Any additional suggestions (to BrokenGlass)? What about `SynchronizationContext`?

Comment: `SynchronizationContext` might work, but that would be a low-level abstract. [My take](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21968329/1768303) is to use TPL and a custom task scheduler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [TPL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) and a custom task scheduler for this, similar to Stephen Toub's [`StaTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx). That's what `WorkerWithTaskScheduler` implements below. In this case, the worker thread is also a task scheduler, which can run arbitrary `Task` items (with `ExecutePendingTasks`) while doing the work on its main loop.

Executing a lambda wrapped as a TPL `Task` on the worker thread's context is a very convenient way to send the worker thread a message and get back the result. This can be done synchrounsly with `WorkerWithTaskScheduler.Run().Wait/Result` or asynchronously with `await WorkerWithTaskScheduler.Run()`. Note how `ContinueExecution` and `WaitForPendingTasks` are used to pause/resume/end the worker's main loop. I hope the code is self-explanatory, but let me know if I should clarify anything.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console_21628490
{
    // Test
    class Program
    {
        static async Task DoWorkAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initial thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            // the worker thread lambda
            Func<WorkerWithTaskScheduler<int>, int> workAction = (worker) =>
            {
                var result = 0;

                Console.WriteLine("Worker thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                while (worker.ContinueExecution)
                {
                    // observe cancellation
                    worker.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    // executed pending tasks scheduled with WorkerWithTaskScheduler.Run
                    worker.ExecutePendingTasks();

                    // do the work item
                    Thread.Sleep(200); // simulate work payload
                    result++;

                    Console.Write("\rDone so far: " + result);
                    if (result > 100)
                        break; // done after 100 items
                }
                return result;
            };

            try
            {
                // cancel in 30s
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(30000);
                // start the worker
                var worker = new WorkerWithTaskScheduler<int>(workAction, cts.Token);

                // pause upon Enter
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to pause...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                worker.WaitForPendingTasks = true;

                // resume upon Enter
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to resume...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                worker.WaitForPendingTasks = false;

                // send a "message", i.e. run a lambda inside the worker thread
                var response = await worker.Run(() =>
                {
                    // do something in the context of the worker thread
                    return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                }, cts.Token);
                Console.WriteLine("\nReply from Worker thread: " + response);

                // End upon Enter
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to stop...");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // worker.EndExecution() to get the result gracefully
                worker.ContinueExecution = false; // or worker.Cancel() to throw
                var result = await worker.WorkerTask;

                Console.Write("\nFinished, result: " + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                while (ex is AggregateException)
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoWorkAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to Exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    //
    // WorkerWithTaskScheduler
    //

    public class WorkerWithTaskScheduler<TResult> : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
    {
        readonly CancellationTokenSource _workerCts;
        Task<TResult> _workerTask;

        readonly BlockingCollection<Task> _pendingTasks;
        Thread _workerThread;

        volatile bool _continueExecution = true;
        volatile bool _waitForTasks = false;

        // start the main loop
        public WorkerWithTaskScheduler(
            Func<WorkerWithTaskScheduler<TResult>, TResult> executeMainLoop,
            CancellationToken token)
        {
            _pendingTasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
            _workerCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);

            _workerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult>(() =>
            {
                _workerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
                return executeMainLoop(this);
            }, _workerCts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
        }

        // a sample action for WorkerWithTaskScheduler constructor
        public static void ExecuteMainLoop(WorkerWithTaskScheduler<TResult> worker)
        {
            while (!worker.ContinueExecution)
            {
                worker.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                worker.ExecutePendingTasks();
            }
        }

        // get the Task
        public Task<TResult> WorkerTask
        {
            get { return _workerTask; }
        }

        // get CancellationToken 
        public CancellationToken Token
        {
            get { return _workerCts.Token; }
        }

        // check/set if the main loop should continue
        public bool ContinueExecution
        {
            get { return _continueExecution; }
            set { _continueExecution = value; }
        }

        // request cancellation
        public void Cancel()
        {
            _workerCts.Cancel();
        }

        // check if we're on the correct thread
        public void VerifyWorkerThread()
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread != _workerThread)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid thread.");
        }

        // check if the worker task itself is still alive
        public void VerifyWorkerTask()
        {
            if (_workerTask == null || _workerTask.IsCompleted)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The worker thread has ended.");
        }

        // make ExecutePendingTasks block or not block
        public bool WaitForPendingTasks
        {
            get { return _waitForTasks; }
            set 
            { 
                _waitForTasks = value;
                if (value) // wake it up
                    Run(() => { }, this.Token);
            }
        }

        // execute all pending tasks and return
        public void ExecutePendingTasks()
        {
            VerifyWorkerThread();

            while (this.ContinueExecution)
            {
                this.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                Task item;
                if (_waitForTasks)
                {
                    item = _pendingTasks.Take(this.Token);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!_pendingTasks.TryTake(out item))
                        break;
                }

                TryExecuteTask(item);
            }
        }

        //
        // TaskScheduler methods
        //

        protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
        {
            _pendingTasks.Add(task);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
        {
            return _pendingTasks.ToArray();
        }

        protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(
            Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
        {
            return _workerThread == Thread.CurrentThread &&
                TryExecuteTask(task);
        }

        public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_workerTask != null)
            {
                _workerCts.Cancel();
                _workerTask.Wait();
                _pendingTasks.Dispose();
                _workerTask = null;
            }
        }

        //
        // Task.Factory.StartNew wrappers using this task scheduler
        //

        public Task Run(Action action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            VerifyWorkerTask();
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, this);
        }

        public Task<T> Run<T>(Func<T> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            VerifyWorkerTask();
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, this);
        }

        public Task Run(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            VerifyWorkerTask();
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, this).Unwrap();
        }

        public Task<T> Run<T>(Func<Task<T>> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            VerifyWorkerTask();
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, this).Unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

To implement worker-to-client notifications, you can use [the `IProgress<T>` pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx) ([example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357567/1768303)).

Comment: This looks very interesting. I will check it out. Thanks for sharing that much information! May I ask what you edited?

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind, and the cleanest approach imo is to have the background thread method that is continuously running be an instance method of a class. This class instance can then expose properties/methods that allow others to change state (e.g. through the UI) - some locking may be required since you are reading/updating state from different threads.

Comment: With this you mean do to `new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadWorkerInstance.RunMethod));` and manipulate the `threadWorkerInstance` from main thread and have `RunMethod` looking for them?

Comment: Yes, essentially - don't forget to put locks in place to handle concurrency.